# Gel electrophoresis and foam

Tags: gel-electrophoresis

[image: Foam appeared while DNA electrophoresis]
I've never seen this kind of thing happen. What might trigger this??

Comment: Looks like an agarose gel. What buffer did you use? Did you happen to clean the tank (incompletely) using a detergent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gas bubbles are foamed by electrolysis of water, generating bubbles of hydrogen gas on the negative electrode and oxygen gas on the positive electrode.

As for the foam itself... I am guessing there is some form of detergent in the buffer. Some electrophoresis buffers do contain detergent.